# Looping through dynamic input boxes and inserting into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, for-loop, foreach

I need your help with my form. I'm trying to build a dynamic forms, whereby a specific integer entered in a previous form sp1.php is used to display the number of input boxes.

The variables from the first forms are $state and $number. Then on the handling page sp2.php, the value of $number is put into a for loop to display the input boxes.

What I'm trying to do now is that the values entered into the tinput boxes are inserted into a mysql table.

The error I'm getting are

1) Undefined Index : DISTRICT
2) Invalid Argument supplied for foreach()

Please how can I make this work. Thank you.

My Code is below.. I'll be more than happy to show other parts of the code, if required.
Thank you.

```
<?php 

 $state=htmlspecialchars(($_POST['state']))       ; 
 $number = intval(($_POST['number']));

  for ($i = 0; $i < $number ; $i++ ) { 

  echo "
  <form action='sd2.php' method='post'>
    <label for='name'>Districts</label>
    <input type='text' name='district[]'>
    <br/><br/>
  </form>"; 

    }
    ?>   
    <?php     

 foreach($_POST['district'] as $senatorial) {
     $query = "INSERT INTO  state  ( `state_id`, `state`, `senatorial`)
     VALUES (NULL, '".$state."', '".$senatorial."') "; 
     mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());  
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: So you know: The for attribute of the <label> tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together.

Answer (score 2):

This must work:

```
$count = count($_POST['district']);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $district = $_POST['district'][$i];
    //do this
    //do that
}
```

Comment: Try to print the values of $_POST and check that if you get the district or anything else.

Comment: Try this: 
    print_r($_POST);

Comment: I have done that.. Now the array is formed and showing like this

array([distinct]=> Array ([0]=> [1]=>)) [submit]=>Register)

which is what I'm expecting.

But I still get undefined Index for District.

Comment: Was "array([distinct]=>" in your last comment a typo, or is it actually distinct, not district?